# Regex in Freepascal - Unrecognized modifier: Pos 15

Tags: regex, pascal, freepascal, lazarus, delphi-10.3-rio

I use regex in Delphi for parsing M3U files and the tags in the M3U file. Most "tags" are in the format

```
tag-name="value"
```

When i use the following regex in Delphi (10.1-10.3) it works fine:

```
(?<=x-tvg-url=")(.*?)(?=")
```

But in freepascal (OSX Lazarus V2.0.8) i keep getting the error:

```
Unrecognized modifier (Pos 15)
```

I dont see what the error is - i tried modifying the regex, but when i test the regex online (https://regexr.com/) it works without a problem.

I did reformat the regex to this:

```
/(?<=x-tvg-url=")(.*?)(?=")/i
```

but no luck whatever i try.. I dont see what it is that im doing wrong, or what the unrecognized modifier is - did i not escape a character? Is there someone that can help me find out what it is i am doing wrong?

Comment: You need to find out what flavour of regex your regex library is using

Comment: Well im using TRegExpr unit from sorokin.engineer

Comment: So find out what regex flavour it uses then, and take it from there. If you want to use the same regex in Delphi as fpc then look for a PCRE based regex library.

Comment: Okay thank you - i "assumed" that it would be the same, but ill look for it in the docs. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with this regex:

```
(?:x-tvg-url=")(.*?)(?:")
```